# How to create a array of an object that requires parameters

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, jbutton

I have some code here

```
final Ship[] Ships = new Ship[3];

for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
    Ships[x].setText("Set Ship length: " + (x+1)); // this line in particular
}
```

I am getting a null pointer exception, I think this is because the Ships object requires a string and a int in its parameters for the constructors that it contains, how are you supposed to create and array of objects where each object requires parameters?

Comment: It's the same way you create an array of objects that don't require parameters.

Answer (score 2):

**Change the code below..**

```
final Ship[] Ships = new Ship[3];

for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
    Ships[x].setText("Set Ship length: " + (x+1)); // this line in particular
}
```

**to...**

```
final Ship[] Ships = new Ship[3];

for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
    String stringValue = "Set Ship length: " + (x+1); //string you want in your ship object
    int intValue = 0; //int you want in your ship object..
    Ship ship = new Ship(stringValue, intValue);
    Ships[x] = ship;
    Ships[x].setText("whatever string your heart desires"); // this line in particular
}
```

You are making an array of the type Ship, **but you never assign any contents** to the array. Therefore when you try to set the text of an element in the array, you are trying to set the text on a null value which will give you a **Null Pointer Exception**.

Instead what you need to do is **first create an object of type Ship** as I have shown above and **pass in the string and integer parameters** that you spoke of in the question. Then **add this new object** to your array. Now you can access the object in the array and call methods on that object.

Comment: Note: not all of the extra code is required. The important part is `Ships[x] = new Ship(...);`.

Comment: Thanks @immibis I just wanted to walk through it step by step for clarity to the OP

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable type [Object], [int], [String] of the array...

example:

```
Object[] Ships = new Object[length]
```

Length would be eg. 8,9,10 - the length of the array

Also use:

```
Ships[x].setText(String.valueOf(blah...))
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create the Ship object before you can call any methods on it.

```
Ships[x] = new Ship(whatever);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
Ship[] ships = new Ship[]
{ 
    new Ship("ship1", 1), 
    new Ship("ship2", 2), 
    new Ship("ship3", 3)
};
```

Or this way:

```
Ship ship1 = new Ship("ship1", 1);
Ship ship1 = new Ship("ship2", 2); 
Ship ship1 = new Ship("ship3", 3);

Ship[] ships = new Ship[]{ship1, ship2, ship3};
```

Its an array initializer. The array will be as long as the elements you put between the brackets {} (separated by commas), 3 in this case.

As Josh Engelsma said, when you simply do "new Ship[3]", the only thing you create is an array that can hold 3 Ship objects, but you don't create any ship. Thus you get a null value  by accessing the array without initializing it first.

With array initializers, the example you posted would be the equivalent of doing:

```
Ship[] ships = new Ship[]
{ 
    null, 
    null, 
    null
};
```

So you get a Ship array of length 3, but all its values are null.